# I dont know javascript and need assistance with a html navbar function

Tags: javascript, html, css, function, web

So here is the code

What is wrong with it?
it should trigger a block if I click on this block (burger) the nav-active function should be triggered.
Here is the JS part:

```
const navSlide = () => {
    const burger = document.querySelector('.burger');
    const nav = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-links');

    burger.addEventListener('click',()=>{
        nav.classList.toggle('nav-active');
    });
}

navSlide();
```

My CSS

```css
.nav-active {
    transform: translate(0%);
}
```

I added the javascript file at the end of my html file:

```
<script src="../static/java_file.js"></script>
```

Comment: `querySelectorAll()` returns you a collection of elements. So there is no classList in a collection. You have to iterate over nav with `forEach`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll#accessing_the_matches

Comment: I would recommend actually learning javascript. My recommendation would be this course on Khan Academy: https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-programming/programming

Comment: Without knowing javascript its not recommended to use DHTML .

Comment: thanks a lot i ll consider it after I finished python @httpanand I use flask actually

Comment: @Wyrden ok:) Flask is ok if you know python a bit

Comment: Please show us your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Since [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) returns a [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) object, you need to iterate every nav link using [`.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) or using a loop like `for`:

```
const navSlide = () => {
    const burger = document.querySelector('.burger');
    const nav = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-links');

    burger.addEventListener('click',() => {

        // nav is a collection, so we use .forEach()
        nav.forEach(n => n.classList.toggle('nav-active'));
    });
}

navSlide();
```

*Small tipps: Use your in-browser developer tools (opened usually by pressing F12) to check for the exact exception messages. Also: don't call your javascript-file 'java_file.js'.*